# Force between two charged particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Consider two positively charged particles, one of charge $q_0$ (particle 0) fixed at the origin, and another of charge $q_1$ (particle 1) fixed on the y-axis at $(0,d_1,0)$. What is the net force $\vec{F}$ on particle 0 due to particle 1?

Express your answer (a vector) using any or all of $k$, $q_0$, $q_1$, $d_1$, $\hat{i}$, $\hat{j}$, and $\hat{k}$.

Using Couloumb's law, I computed

$\frac{k q_0 q_1}{d_1^2} \hat{j}$.

I'm not sure if this is correct. I would like some to correct it for me if it is.

Comment: To clarify, do you have 2 charges (q0 and q1) both on the y axis, separated by distance d1?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is what the questions states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. Coulumb's Law can be written $$ F = k \frac{Q_1 Q_2} {r^2} \hat{j} $$ where your $ d_1^2 $ is the distance labeled as $ r^2 $, and $ k = \frac {1} {4\pi \epsilon_0} $. $ \epsilon_0 $ is the permittivity of free space: $ 8.85418782 × 10^{-12} m^{-3} kg^{-1} s^4 A^2 $

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if had a third particle with a negative charge at (0,-d1, 0) on the y-axis. Would this be the correct answer:$ (k q_{0} (q2d1−q1d2))d_12d_22j^ \frac{\left(kq_{0}\left(q_{2}d_{1}-q_{1}d_{2}\right)\ri‌​ght)}{d_{1}{^{2}}d_{2}{^{2}}}\hat{j $

Comment: That could be viewed as the same situation as moving the origin of your coordinate system to the other particle. Since that distance between them still does not change, the force will be the same, however the direction will be changed. This is a restatement of Newton's 3rd Law ( Forces come in reciprocal pairs ) as well as showing how the distance between two objects doesn't change when you translate your coordinate system to a different point in space. That's a relativity concept.

Answer (score 0):

Since the force is directed from $q_0$ to $q_1$, you should also consider the case when $d_1$ is negative.

A combined answer could be written as:

$\vec F=\frac {kq_0 q_1}{d_1^2}(d_1/|d_1|) \hat{j}$